# Unit 'MMSystem' not found

Tags: pascal

Using Windows 8.1 coding with PascalABC.NET

Trying to use MMSystem to play sounds but it says:
Unit 'MMSystem' not found
before "var" I entered "uses MMSystem;" did I do something wrong?

Comment: `MMSystem.pas` is a wrapper around the Windows Multimedia API. It's part of the Delphi WinAPI support. Unless PascalABC.Net (which is not Delphi) also includes the same unit, you won't have it. Do you have a `MMSystem.pas` on your computer anywhere? You can't use it if you don't have it.

Comment: 1) you don't show code. 2) PascalABC.Net seems to be a C# with a global pascal syntax, and is not really standard.

Comment: Where do I get the MMSystem.pas?

Comment: I told you that in my previous comment.  **It's part of the Delphi WinAPI support.** If you don't have Delphi, you don't have it. Do you have Delphi? If  not, you can't get one of Delphi's units.